# My mesh that is weight painted to a specific bone is moving weirdly when another bone is moved when

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have a mechanical part that I have applied weight paint to be completely red so that it will stay put in it's parented bone but as soon as I move the arm of the character this specific mechanical part that sits on the upper lip and a plate on the chest starts to deform in a wierd way.the mechanical part on the upper lip is weight painted to be a part of the head bone and the chest piece paint is applied to be a part of the torso bone. Both of these deform creating spike like deformations on them when the hand IK is moved

Comment: Probably other bones also have some unwanted weight on them. The Weight Paint is handling the vertex groups what you can find in the mesh properties panel. If you want paint fully something you better use the vertex groups instead of the Weight Paint mode. There you can easily assign and remove "weights" in Edit mode. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/introduction.html

Comment: Select the mesh, and in the Vertex Groups panel click on Remove from All Groups, then reassign to the desired group